# Passing a file as param in Mojolicious controller unit test

Tags: perl, testing, file-upload, mojolicious

I have a file upload application. I want to test my `Upload` controller. For that how do I pass a file to my test? For file upload in my application I use an external application/plugin (Flash/HTML5/HTML4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow like this:

```
use Test::Mojo;

my $t = Test::Mojo->new('MyApp');

$t->post_form_ok('/my_action', {my_upload => {file => '/path/to/file'}});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was trying something like `$t->param(file => '/path')`